# org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity
public class Player implements IPlayer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String name;

    String email;

    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Player(String name, String email) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Player() {
        super();
    }

}



@Entity
public class DhaadiPlayer {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;

    int availableCoins;

    BitSet positions = new BitSet(24);

    boolean allowRemove;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Player.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id", nullable = false)
    Player player;



    public DhaadiPlayer() {
        super();
    }
}


I am persisting Player with one DAO call
when I am trying to persist DhaadiPlayer ,  I am getting error


Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.rjns.game.Player.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4260)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3982)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.isNullifiable(ForeignKeys.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.nullifyTransientReferences(ForeignKeys.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys$Nullifier.nullifyTransientReferences(ForeignKeys.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:705)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:853)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.rjns.game.Player.id to com.rjns.dhaadi.DhaadiPlayer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    ... 35 more
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: what is the relation between Player and DhaadiPlayer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem related to the relationship between the two classes.

Either do not use `@JoinColumn` in DhaadiPlayer class or provide the `mappedBy` attribute in the `targetEntity` `Player` aswell.